# Init no data inside scrollview and add later nothing display

Tags: swiftui

I create list of items with empty at the first place. And then i add later by pressing record audio at the bottom of screen. Once I press again it will put into the array. Any idea ?
Here is an example project https://github.com/tylerlantern/VoiceRecorderIOS.

What the application does is that It will record your sound and save and display towards users.

The array is named as `audioFiles`. You can start from that.
The function that add array is named `audioRecorderDidFinishRecording`. 
Thank in advance

Comment: SwiftUI `ScrollView` needs to know some initial size, so just add stub item (invisible, but non-zero size), which can be removed as soon as real items are added.

Comment: Is there a better way ?